# Not getting logged-in user id in Wordpress 3.4

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a Paypal plugin and modifying that as per my requirements. For that I want to get the user id of the current user on the payment.php page; I have tried various functions such as `wp_get_current_user()`, `is_logged_in()`, `get_current_user_id()` etc but I am not getting the user id in payment page.

I am getting the user id on other pages.

Below is the code of payment page

```
public static function insert_payment( $data, $transaction_id = 0 ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $sql = "SELECT transaction_id
                FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "wpuf_transaction
                WHERE transaction_id = '" . $wpdb->escape( wpuf_clean_tags( $transaction_id ) ) . "' LIMIT 1";

        $result = $wpdb->get_row( $sql );
        $tran = $wpdb->escape( wpuf_clean_tags( $transaction_id ) );
    if($tran !="")
    {

        if ( !$result ) 
        {
                $log_user_id=get_current_user_id(); // Not Getting user id here
                $log_user_id = $data['user_id'];
                $find_user_id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT user_id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "wpuf_transaction WHERE user_id=".$log_user_id);                
                $find_user_id123 =  $find_user_id->user_id;
                if($find_user_id123=='')
                {
                    $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'wpuf_transaction', $data );
                    do_action( 'wpuf_payment_received', $data );
                }
                else
                {
                     $wpdb->update( $wpdb->prefix . 'wpuf_transaction', $data, array('user_id' => $log_user_id) );
                }
        }

}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated; thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$log_user_id = $current_user->ID;
```

Comment: :Thanks for your reply, i have tried this option but not working.

Comment: Have you check what you are getting in `$current_user` also try to check in your session it should contain current user id...

Comment: In the payment page i am using, there i cannot echo,die anything so it is unable to check what i am getting in $log_user_id

Comment: @Swap, it doesn't give much to go on to say "this option is not working". Try digging into the problem, and do some debugging. Answers on StackOverflow are very often clues that will help you to solve your problem, but only you are implementing it, so you will need to do some work as well. Would you say why you are unable to echo/die to see the state of your intermediate variables?

Comment: I have got my solution with debuging the page line by line.small loop miskate

Answer (score 0):

You may use like , sometime we get some syntax error spell mistakes:

[reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)